# Как передать переменные в другой handler

Tags: python, функции, aiogram

На примере я показываю реализацию обработки реферальных ссылок для телеграм бота

```
ref_id_1lv = ''
ref_id_2lv = ''
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_message(message: types.Message):
    try:
        start, payload = message.text.strip().split()
        try:
 
            ref_id_1lv, ref_id_2lv = payload.strip().split('_')
        except:
            ref_id_1lv = payload
            ref_id_2lv = None
        global ref_id_1lv, ref_id_2lv
        key = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        key.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Я согласен/согласна', callback_data = 'agree'))
        text = str(config.start_message_for_user)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text, parse_mode = '', reply_markup = key)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data == 'agree')
async def agree_ref_start(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
  if callback.data == 'agree':
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET status = 1 WHERE chat_id = {callback.from_user.id};')
    cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET ref_id_1lv = {ref_id_1lv} WHERE chat_id = {callback.from_user.id};')
    cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET ref_id_2lv = {ref_id_2lv} WHERE chat_id = {callback.from_user.id};')
    cur.execute(f'SELECT how_mach_ref FROM users WHERE chat_id = {ref_id_1lv} and chat_id = {ref_id_2lv};')
    for how_mach_ref in cur.fetchmany(2):
        how_mach_ref1 = how_mach_ref[0]
        how_mach_ref2 = how_mach_ref[1]
    cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET how_mach_ref = {how_mach_ref1 + 1} WHERE chat_id = {ref_id_1lv};')
    cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET how_mach_ref = {how_mach_ref2 + 1} WHERE chat_id = {ref_id_2lv};')
    con.commit()
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, 'Всё Ок')
```

Но проблема в реализации функции. Как можно передать переменные `ref_id_1lv` и `ref_id_2lv` в хэндлер с callback-ами

Код ошибки:

```
File "telegrambot.py", line 103, in agree_ref_start
    cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET ref_id_1lv = {ref_id_1lv} WHERE chat_id = {callback.from_user.id};')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать FSM aiogram'а. Пример использования есть [здесь](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py)

Для начала, вам нужно импортировать `FSMContext` и, на пример, `MemoryStorage`

```py
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
```

Далее указать `MemoryStorage` в Dispatcher'е. Выглядеть это будет примерно так

```py
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
```

Чтобы передать переменные в другой обработчик, вам нужно вписать в аргументы функций `state: FSMContext`

`async def start_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):`

`async def agree_ref_start(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):`

Далее, в функции `start_message` сохраняете переменную. Работает как словарь:

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
    data['ref1'] = ref_id_1lv
    data['ref2'] = ref_id_2lv
```

Теперь, в функции `agree_ref_start` достаем эти переменные:

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
    ref_id_1lv = data['ref1']
    ref_id_2lv = data['ref2']
```

После этого не забываем почистить все эти переменные из памяти: `await state.finish()`

Если что-то непонятно, приложу готовый для вас код:

```py
# Импортируем нужное
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

# Не забудьте в Dispatcher прописать MemoryStorage

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        start, payload = message.text.strip().split()
        try:
            ref_id_1lv, ref_id_2lv = payload.strip().split('_')
        except:
            ref_id_1lv = payload
            ref_id_2lv = None
        # Сохраняем переменные
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['ref1'] = ref_id_1lv 
            data['ref2'] = ref_id_2lv 
        key = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        key.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Я согласен/согласна', callback_data = 'agree'))
        text = str(config.start_message_for_user)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text, parse_mode = '', reply_markup = key)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data == 'agree')
async def agree_ref_start(callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
  if callback.data == 'agree':
    # Достаем переменные
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        ref_id_1lv = data['ref1']
        ref_id_2lv = data['ref2']
        
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET status = 1 WHERE chat_id = {callback.from_user.id};')
        cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET ref_id_1lv = {ref_id_1lv} WHERE chat_id = {callback.from_user.id};')
        cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET ref_id_2lv = {ref_id_2lv} WHERE chat_id = {callback.from_user.id};')
        cur.execute(f'SELECT how_mach_ref FROM users WHERE chat_id = {ref_id_1lv} and chat_id = {ref_id_2lv};')
        for how_mach_ref in cur.fetchmany(2):
            how_mach_ref1 = how_mach_ref[0]
            how_mach_ref2 = how_mach_ref[1]
        cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET how_mach_ref = {how_mach_ref1 + 1} WHERE chat_id = {ref_id_1lv};')
        cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET how_mach_ref = {how_mach_ref2 + 1} WHERE chat_id = {ref_id_2lv};')
        con.commit()
        await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, 'Всё Ок')
        
        await state.finish() # Завершаем FSM, очищаем переменные
```

Это решение лучше, чем использование глобальных переменных. Потому что, насколько я знаю, если использовать глобальные переменные и несколько человек будут использовать бота одновременно, то значения эти переменных могут перепутаться и использоваться не у того пользователя, у которого нужно было.

В данном же случае, эти переменные сохраняются для только конкретного человека и у других пользователей использовать их не получится

Answer (score 0):

Сделать глобальними и брать их с другой функции
Но чтобы в функции изменить значение глобальной переменной напишите
`global ref_id_1lv, ref_id_2lv` - в вашем случае
Или же записать в бд, но тогда изучите **sqlite3** на Python

Comment: Сделал по вашему совету, но появилась новая проблема. Я отредактировал вопрос что бы было понятно где искать. В чем ошибка?:(

Comment: Переделайте ту строчку на ету `cur.execute('UPDATE users SET ref_id_1lv =? WHERE chat_id = ?', ref_id_1lv,callback.from_user.id)`